# Exclude folders from Eclipse search

Tags: eclipse, search

Is there a way to exclude certain folders (and all their subfolders) from searching within Eclipse?

Comment: Googlers: see (atzz's answer:) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111002/1599699 - this is the answer you're looking for, not the accepted answer.

Comment: @Andrew this is now the accepted answer

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Here is what works for me (I'm using Helios - maybe this way was not available when this question was originally asked?)

- Go to Project -> Properties -> Resource Filters.
- Click *Add*.
- Choose *Filter type*: *Exclude all*
- Choose *Applies to*: *Folders*; check *All children (recursive)*.
- In the Attributes, choose *Name*, *Matches*, `.svn` (for example).

(Actually, I'm using `.*` to filter out .svn, .hg etc. in one go.)

After okay'ing the project properties dialog, these directories won't come up in search any more. In fact, Eclipse is so kind as to automatically update *existing* search results windows and remove all matches which are now filtered out.

Comment: For latest versions of Eclipse as of 2011 (Helios & Indigo), this should be the accepted answer and the easiest way to do it.

Comment: As this can only be applied to one project at a time, it's really not a gain over marking folders derived... and depending on how many times you need to type in the filters, it could take longer.

Comment: When using this method, be sure to also clear your search history (using the flashlight-with-a-down-arrow button in the search panel) after adding the resource filter.  Otherwise you won't save any search time, and you'll get `.git/.../filename.file doesn't exist` errors because the search cache (I think?) still considers the .git folder to be a valid place to look.

Comment: This works but hides the files in the package explorer. We may want to edit the files but not see them in search results.

Comment: When I tried, this it worked for filtering search results, but I started getting errors "Errors running builder 'AspectJ Builder' on project 'Mercadosa-webapp'.
Resource already exists on disk: '/MyProject/target/MyProject-1.0/WEB-INF/freemarker/site/file.ftl'.
Resource already exists on disk: '/MyProject/target/MyProject-1.0/WEB-INF/freemarker/site/file.ftl'."

Comment: Just like @AramKocharyan said.  for that reason, I prefer the answer from Dave Ray.

Comment: In Mars, probably earlier versions as well, access through:  Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters

Comment: This. is. awesome. I gave it a shot, and it live=filtered my existing searches. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe don't do this. After I add ".*" my ESP32 CDT build broke. Then I removed the filter and did Project->Clean and it worked again. Just a coincidence?

Comment: This solution is not ideal, as it also hides files from the "Package Explorer" view (not just searches).

Answer (score 300):

**The quick and dirty way:**

Right click on a folder, go to properties, and mark a folder as derived. Derived entities are excluded from searching by default. *The problem with this approach is that Eclipse "forgets" that the folder is derived if you delete it* (either from within Eclipse or externally, followed by refreshing the project tree). Like so often with Eclipse, this is a [long-standing bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=154089) (10 years in this case) which still applies to the current version (4.6 Neon at the time of writing).

**The safe way:**

Create a working set including only those entities you want searched and search only within that working set. See [Dave Ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443220/25050) for details on this procedure.

Comment: Like Dave noted in his answer: setting things that are not really derived to be derived might cause problems. Like when using Maven to create a distribution.

Comment: In Juno, marking a folder as derived does not exclude it from search. I'm working on Mac OS so it may be related to that as I'm seeing a number of features not working correctly on this OS

Comment: Works for me on Juno SR2 under MS-Windows XP. And the folder that annoyed me was actually derived (the build folder, with listing files sometimes resulting in  zillions of hits).

Comment: @Instantsoup Why can't the search itself exclude the folders? I mean, it has the "!" character just for this, no? I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Creating 'a working set including only those entities you want searched' is not a very safe way of doing it. In fact an INCLUSIVE filter is quite unsafe. Imagine creating a new directory or file that is a sibling to one that is excluded. In that instance you will have to remember to INCLUDE it in the search. If you forget, search has false negatives which can be dangerous and lead you to believe that Eclipse search is unreliable.

Comment: Just in case anyone will be wondering at some point, this works on Eclipse's version 4.5.1 for PHP as well. I am posting, because someone asked me, so I guess someone else could be wondering the same.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Concerning your first comment - You're referring to the "File name patterns" section of the search dialog, which is for **file names** not directory/path names.

Comment: It would be nice that eclipse could assume anything matching the `.gitignore` files to be derived. As a matter of fact, in 4.19, it adds it to a local `.gitignore` whenever you mark a folder as 'derived'.

Answer (score 88):

I could imagine that marking resources derived might cause problems in other areas. Instead, create a working set with the folders you want to include in the search:

- Open Search dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Change search scope to Working Set
- Click Choose ...
- Click New to create a new Working Set with the what you want searched (or Add All and then remove the ones you want filtered

Comment: This has issues too. See my comment under Instantsoup's answer above. With this INCLUSIVE filter, in some cases, when you add files or folders you have to remember to include them in search. If you forget you get dangerous false negatives. Which is not ideal.

Comment: In Eclipse Kepler there is a "Select a working set type" dialog that comes up after clicking New. (Worth noting that to find all types of file need to select "Resource" at this point.)

Answer (score 4):

- Right click on your project
- Select `Properties`
- Select `Resource` -> `Resource filters`
- Click `Add filter`
- Choose the following settings:

  - Exclude all
  - Files and folders
  - All children (recursive)
- Change `Name` for `Project Relative Path`
- Fill input text with `(bin$|bin/.*|build/.*|build$)` (replace `bin` and `build` by the names of the folders you want to exclude)
- Tick `Regular expression`

Hit OK and then Apply.

### Disclaimer

This builds on @atzz's answer, which helped me figure this out. However while it did answer the question of how to exclude certain files, it didn't answer the question of how to exclude certain folders.

Answer (score 1):

**The best quick and dirty way in Eclipse Juno:**

1. Right click on the **folder**.
2. Go to Properties.
3. Go to C/C++ Build.
4. Check "Exclude resource from build".
5. Click in OK button.
6. Right click on the **project**.
7. Go to Index.
8. Click Rebuild.
9. Relax!

Answer (score 0):

Excluding a folder or file from being searched in Eclipse

```
1 Right-click on the file/folder.
3 Click on the "Properties" option.
4 Select the "Resource" option.
5 Place a check next to the "Derived" attribute.
```

Hope is help.