# How to skip .svn-base files in file search of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search

Whenever i perform a file search in eclipse, it scans all files including .svn-base file.
*Provided i am using `*` for file name patterns.*

Is it possible to scan all files for searching but skipping the .svn-base file?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/eclipse-exclude-folders-from-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have [custom plugins](http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/ary/2009/06/19/eclipse-plugin-to-exclude-svn-and-cvs-folders-in-text-search/) for excluding `.svn` and `.cvs` directories during searches.

If you have [**Subclipse**](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), the search filtering is included.

Note: since [Eclipse Helios 3.6M3](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M3-200910301201/eclipse-news-M3.html) (October 30, 2009), you can actually exclude resources from your project, making the search more precise as a result.

[alt text http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M3-200910301201/images/resourceFilters.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M3-200910301201/images/resourceFilters.png)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. But the search pattern is inclusive and not exclusive. You can click on *Choose* button and select the file types you wish to see in your search results.