# Exclude target folder from search results in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven-2

I was wondering if it's possible to **exclude target** folder from **eclipse quick search** :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

If anyone knows how to do that, please advise.

Update: I am using **Maven 2**, and **M2E** , **WTP** Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: Are you working in the context of Maven 2/3? Are you using any additional plugins? Do you have an example where a resource is in a target and non-target folder?

Comment: Related: [Exclude folders from Eclipse search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/eclipse-exclude-folders-from-search)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

1. Mark the "target" folders as "derived" resource from the properties screen of those folders (this option is next to read only and archive property).
2. In the quick search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) screen press the arrow in the top right corner and untick "Show derived resources".

Then those target-files will not be considered in the quick search anymore.

Comment: what when the target gets recreated through external mvn clean install

Comment: does not work for me. Eclipse version:  2022-06 (4.24.0)

Comment: The second answer using a filter is much more elegant and works also in Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0).

Answer (score 46):

## Go to *Add Resource Filter* preferences dialog:

Go to `Project` → `Properties` → `Resource` → `Resource Filters`

Click `Add Filter...`

## Then fill the options:

#### Filter type:

`(`**`•`**`)`*Exclude all*

#### Applies to:

`(`**`•`**`)`*Folders*

`[`**`X`**`]` *All children (recursive)*

#### Filter and Folder Attributes:

`Name` - `Matches` - `[`*target*`]`

Comment: The best solution with no doubt.

Comment: Our project is rather big and consists of three working sets with more than 200 subprojects which even change depending on the branch you're working on. Not a good solution for me to edit every single project.

Comment: If you have imported your parent maven project all files are found twice (once with project path and once with parent project path). If you "Add Group - Exclude all, Files and Folders" it won't happen.

Comment: Hello, can we do it for all projects in the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

You can install **AutoDeriv plugin** from Eclipse Marketplace or http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv/. It allows you to create either global(workspace) or per-project `.derived` files in which you can specify which files/folders should be marked as derived.

Here's a sample config file (taken from plugin's homepage):

```
# set the 'target' and 'ext' folders as derived
target
ext
# but don't affect the 'keep' sub-folder
!target/keep
# all files with a '.dep' extension are generated
*.dep
src/include/version.h # this specific file is also generated.
```

Comment: I'm, using that "AutoDeriv" plugin now and it correctly sets all the "target" folders as derived, but when I press ctrl+shift+R I'm still getting suggestions from files that are inside "target" folders (even from those of other projects that the current one sees)... And yes, I've unchecked the "show derived resources" flag... :(