# How to show only (src) files not (target) files by Eclipse shortcut (cntrl + alt + R)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, target, src

By using `Eclipse` shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
Will show both (`src`) files and also (`target`) files.
Like that
[image]

The problem is that
Some times by mistake
I select the target file then i update my changes
After build i will NOT see the new changes !!
Thats because i update the wrong files (target)

So any idea
How to show only (`src`) files not (`target`) files by Eclipse shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213032/exclude-target-folder-from-search-results-in-eclipse

Comment: Hmm. My Eclipse does not do that (shows only src). Some misconfiguration? Are you using the Maven plugin?

Comment: @Thilo Yes i using Maven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The quick and (dirty way) :**

Right click on a `target folder`(s)
Go to folder(s) properties,
Mark folder as `Derived` like that.
[image]
Derived entities are excluded from searching by default like that.
[image]

**The (safe way) :**

By create a `working set`
[image]
That include **only** those entities you want searched and search only within that working set.
In our case will include ALL without `target folder`(s).

Note : This answer is related to
[Exclude folders from Eclipse search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/exclude-folders-from-eclipse-search)

Answer (score 1):

In the project-settings on java build-path you'll find on source a checkbox like this:

[image]

Disable it, for not getting files which are in the target folder to your view.
So you will not find it by Eclipse shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)