# Exclude folders from eclipse - Open resources

Tags: eclipse, search

These two seem to be related, but they are not :
[Exclude folders from Eclipse search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/443169/1083581)
[Exclude target folder from search results in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8213032/1083581)

How can I exclude the target folder (of all projects) when I look for a resource using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ?

I am packaging using maven and my target folder(s) is recreated all the time. Its cumbersome to mark the folders as derived after every single build and I have about 30 sub/projects.
I am on eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this marking of the target folders by using the autoderiv plugin: [nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv](http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv)