# How to hide maven dependencies when searching for Types/References in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I get duplicate findings when searching for a class or its references (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>): the .java file from my open projects and the .class file from Maven Dependencies (.m2\repo jars):

```
+ com.commonbackoffice - server-utils-commonlogin-0.1.jar - C:\Users\...\.m2\repository\com\commonlogin\0.1 - server-login
+ com.commonbackoffice - src/main/java - server-utils-commonlogin
```

How can I hide the .class findings from these results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Go to Project > Properties > Resource > Resource Filters

Click Add Filter...

Filter type:

Exclude all
Applies to:

Folders
Check All children (recursive)
Filter Details:

Name
Matches
Type in the text box: target
```

There are a lot of ways, you can check this links:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213032/exclude-target-folder-from-search-results-in-eclipse) and
[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797438/eclipse-maven-showing-multiple-paths-for-the-same-file)

Comment: This does not work. I also tried .m2 instead of target.