# How do I prevent Eclipse search from looking in the .git directory?

Tags: eclipse, git

I can't see how to tell Eclipse to ignore the .git directory when doing a project-wide search (^H), so it either finds irrelevant stuff in .git or complains "Resource is out of sync".

I don't use any Eclipse-git plug-ins - I find them too confining compared to the command-line.

Is it possible to configure this?

(If there's an answer to this already, it isn't tagged with both eclipse and git.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/eclipse-exclude-folders-from-search

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution makes me a bit embarrassed to have asked the question in the first place: set the search Scope to be a Working Set, and then using Choose to set up a scope including only the directories you want to look in.

Answer (score -1):

You can put .git folder on level higher.
I.e. a root project directory contains only directories .git and folder with a real project.

Git perfectly tracks moving and renaming files so it can be done easily.

Comment: That would certainly be a good place to start with a new project, but unfortunately I'm working on an existing project, and I think folks would object to a mass move.