# AndroidManifest.xml is missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I created one android application project in eclipse and whenever I tried to run that application its throwing an error message saying `AndroidManifest.xml` file is missing. what is the reason for this ?

I am using eclipse with android-sdk and ADT version is 20. in SDK manager I installed android 2.2 API level only.. Is this is the problem for that error ?

Comment: Well, do you have an AndroidManifest.xml file within your project?

Comment: @mattquiros : Yes I have AndriodManifest.xml

Comment: Try: Click on your project -> Refresh (F5) -> Go to "Project" in the menu bar -> Clean (and clean the project). If all else fails, restart eclipse. Let us know what happens next.

Comment: Puff.. I am tired of these strange problems... good that we have people like you helping us!!!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Delete `bin` folder in project and your library dependencies. Then re-run application.

Comment: hmm ... nothing new compared to earlier answers, is there?

Comment: if your project is referencing other library projects, do the same for the library projects too.

Comment: "Clean all" from Project menu achieved same results

Answer (score 43):

you should clean and refresh your project once.

Comment: its not showing any error mark my project. and my app gen folder is created

Comment: rt clk on project> properties> JAVA build path > see whether any file is missing there.... then clean your project!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by manually deleting the bin directory, as well as the gen directory, right clicking project and selecting Android Tools->Fix Project Properties, then using Project->Build All.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your eclipse and make sure that build  automatically checked. It worked for me all the time. Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 1):

I closed all projects that were unrelated with the one I was trying to run (right-click on project in Project Explorer and then selecting Close Project) and the problem magically disappeared (for no apparent reason). Then, even after I re-opened the closed projects, the problem did not come back.

Answer (score 1):

I put the AndroidManifest.xml that in appcomatv7 and pasted to the project and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Click project -> Refresh (F5) -> Go to "Project" in the menu bar -> Clean. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and didn't understand why - followed all deletes of /bin, /gen, fixing AVD's, etc, still to no avail.

The /bin got me thinking though -

I had previously used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/exclude-folders-from-eclipse-search/443220#443220) advice to exclude /bin from the resource filters (in an effort to remove results from the search)....

I removed the filter for /bin and voila.....

Interesting this only affected me when I wanted to Debug or Run within Eclipse -- I could export a working APK without any problem, but debugging failed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem in android studio after an update , it worked by Tools ->Android ->sync with gradle file

Answer (score 0):

(what worked for me)

1 - copy the file `build.gradle` 
2 - drop the copied file in the android folder [example MyApp/android]

Answer (score 0):

before

After add Package name

add package name