# AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using git, and creating lots of git branches for new features on a project I'm working on. Every once in a while, I'll create a new branch off master as usual (let's call this `broken-branch`, and this error appears:

`Android Source Generator: [demo] AndroidManifest.xml file not found`

I'll create a new branch off master, cherrypick the changes on `broken-branch` onto this one, and everything works fine. Why do I get this error, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AndroidManifest.xml is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525969/androidmanifest-xml-is-missing)

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me today.. I clicked "Sync Project with Gradle Files" and all went fine.

Comment: This happened in Android Studio on a very simple project which crashed before any save. Reopening the problems caused referred to module already disposed. The sync sorted all issues.

Answer (score 5):

While my IDE is IDEA13 with maven. Work fine with maven in command line, while using IDEA run( shift + F10)  show this error. I do as below and fix this:
1.Open .iml in the project root.
2.Find some line like:

```
<option name="USE_CUSTOM_COMPILER_MANIFEST" value="true" />
```

3.Remove this line or change value to false.
This is my work way.
May Help.

Comment: i have not have 'USE_CUSTOM...' this sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I use IntelliJ Idea and found next solution:
in the root of the project (in catalog with root build.gradle) create file `settings.gradle` which consist `include ':app'`
Than go to IDE and run Gradle - refresh.

Answer (score 3):

I know the problem in IDEA because you create a new project with Java configuration (not android, but with android sdk dependency)

```
File > New Project > Java (Java Module) > Project SDK Android 4.X
```

**Here is the solution :**

```
File > New Project > Android (Application Module)
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Maven**, backup the project and close it. Open IntelliJ and select Open..., choose the pom.xml file and then select yes to open this project. Because there is already a project a popup should appear, choose 'Delete Existing Project and Import'.

Note: I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition version 13

Answer (score 2):

When I get "AndroidManifest.xml file not found" error I clean and then refresh the project and these steps seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me when I don't have **.iml** file to open the project. It's very easy to fix, you just need to close the project and reopen it taking care of select **build.gradle** file before click open.

[image]

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: taking care of build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. 
My project already had a settings.gradle file.
I simple had to add the line include ':app' . N ow i can build and do everything.

Answer (score 0):

open IDE

project

|--->build automatically

uncheck it
clean the project

check build automatically opriot

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem while trying to build the swagger code gen project. For whatever reason IntelliJ thought I should have an Android facet. Removing this facet allowed the entire project to build.

Answer (score 0):

If in case, you encounter an error which shows:
`AndroidManifest.xml file is not found`
All that you have to do is reinstall the flutter package and the error is resolved!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go File,Project Structure or press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S,

Go Facets, Select your android project, in the structure there are configuration files, folders. [Image of structure tab (before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1zDI.png)

Location of AndroidManifest file was like this:

`D:\Programming\Dart Flutter Projects\tip_calculator\AndroidManifest.xml`

Change the location like this.
[Image of structure tab (after)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIM9t.png)

Changed it to here:

`D:\Programming\Dart Flutter Projects\tip_calculator\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Helped me.

Works for you?