# androidmanifest.xml not found android studio

Tags: android

I have imported an eclipse project to android studio which worked fine on eclipse  but when I try to run it on android studion it gives me the error

```
Error:Android Source Generator: [MySchoolApp1] AndroidManifest.xml file not found
```

Comment: check your gardle console error.

Comment: Make sure you are following [these guidelines](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the android section of your build.gradle file, you can try adding sourceSets with the manifest.srcFile variable.

```
android {
  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'ToDoList/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
      }
  }
}
```

That path may need to be adjusted slightly.

Reference : [AndroidManifest.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908222/androidmanifest-xml-file-not-found)

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: I didn't find any builde.gradle file I don't have it on my project