# package name is not determined in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-manifest

i am using Android studio 1.5. and at when i click run i receive

```
unable to determine package name
```

i checked the manifest file and it is as shown in the image below...but i do not know why the activities are marked with red even the app name and the icon
as well.

please let me know how to fix this

```
build.gradle:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.bt_11"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file, one for the 'app' module :-)

Comment: @Kelevandos please find it posted above

Comment: just do a `Project > Clean`  , the `unable to determine package name ` is to do with your run config settings, separate from the code

Comment: @Blundell when i clean the project i receive: failed to complete gradle execution

Comment: Delete your build files and clean project again...That should work

Comment: @m0rpheu5 which file please?, do u mean "build.gradle" the one i posted it

Comment: No, no... inside your "app" folder, there will be "build" folders...which will be having generated files of android build system...Delete those folders and clean build your project  again

Comment: The AS screenshot mentions that Gradle project sync failed. What error does it give you - it should show in the 'Messages' tab.

Comment: @zmarkan it gives: unable to connect.connect refused:connect

Comment: Can you post your projects top level build.gradle as well?

Comment: @zmarkan would you please tell me which one exactly...there are many gradles files

Comment: It's the one in your project's root directory.

Comment: @zmarkan i solved the problem by installing AS with same version the projects were created with v1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps as user2121 and eventually tried downgrading to Android Studio 1.4.1. Unlike user2121, I **still** got an error, however it was different than when on 1.5.1.

```
AndroidManifest.xml file not found
```

Upon searching for this new error, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850851/1822968) StackOverflow answer which solved the problem for me on 1.5.1 as well as 1.4.1.