# ERROR: Android Source Generator: [project] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to Android programming; I am using Intellij IDEA. When I compile my hello-world program, I get this error "Android Source Generator: [project] AndroidManifest.xml file not found"

Of course it is not in my root file.
When I make any new project, I have the same problem.

I found this question: [AndroidManifest.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908222/androidmanfiest-xml-file-not-found), but it didn't help. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where in your project structure is androidmanifest.xml?  Is it in the root?

Comment: no it is not! yesterday I ran it but today i have this problem!

Comment: So where is it?  You've searched the project?

Comment: I don't know! :( it's not so I got this problem! can I add this file by myself?

Comment: f it ran yesterday, then it was there.  You've either deleted it or moved it.  Is it in the local history in IDEA?

Comment: how i must rebuild the project? it will solve?

Comment: Delete your project and start again lol

Comment: I done it but now In every new project I have this problem , even I can not make an emulator .

Comment: yeah, I also encountered this problem with new IDEA. Is this a bug ?

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908222/androidmanfiest-xml-file-not-found/20850851#20850851

Comment: Installing the new version of Intellijj idea solved my problem !

Comment: possible duplicate of [AndroidManifest.xml is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525969/androidmanifest-xml-is-missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the problem in IDEA because you create a new project with Java configuration (not android, but with android sdk dependency)

```
File > New Project > Java (Java Module) > Project SDK Android 4.X
```

**Here is the solution :**

```
File > New Project > Android (Application Module)
```

Comment: You need to re-create new project using (Android application module), not Java project

Comment: if you still using your old projects, it will always fail, because IDEA doesn't generate AndroidManifest.xml when using (Java project) as new project SDK.

Comment: tnx for ur answer , but nothing change.

Comment: indeed one of my modules changed to Android configuration while it was a Java module (not sure why it happened but it is other story). I removed Android configuration in **Project Structure / Modules / <Your Module>** and it solved the issue

Answer (score 50):

you must open Project Structure modified something.

example:
Project Structure > Facets ,you can see this is:
[image]

delete ".idea", like this
[image]

ok, IDE there find AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it's not working. ide can't find androidManifest.xml at the update location.

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using Maven**, backup the project and close it. Open IntelliJ and select Open..., choose the pom.xml file and then select yes to open this project. Because there is already a project a popup should appear, choose 'Delete Existing Project and Import'.

Note: I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition version 13

I believe this question is a duplicate of this question: [AndroidManifest.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908222/androidmanfiest-xml-file-not-found/20728254#20728254)

Answer (score 4):

I used to have the same problem with Intellij 13 EAP, OS-X Mavericks, and a maven multi module Android project, where it was compiling fine by command line, but failing to rebuild/make thru the IDE.

Project Structure > Facets > select your Android project > 'Generated Sources' tab

check "Run 'process-resources' Maven task before Make" option.

Answer (score 4):

Please check your Build Tools version, it must be same in build.gradle file, for example:

```
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
```

So, open Android SDK Manager, check your revision of Build Tools.

After changes, go to `Build -> Clean Project`

Answer (score 3):

Go to the directory where you have installed Android SDK. There, go to `tools` directory. Note down the path of `tools` directory.

Open command prompt/terminal, and `cd` to tools directory:

```
cd <tools directory path>
```

Run command:

```
android update project -p <path to project directory> -n <name of project> -t android-15
```

To create a new project:

```
android create project -p <path to project directory> -n <name of project> -k <package name> -a <hello world activity name> -t <android version like: android-15>
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be more than one answer to this. Check that your Android project is not under another directory of the same name. Android Studio is easily confused by this.

For example, change:
/Development/MyProject/MyProject/app/...

to this structure:
/Development/MyProject/app/...

When I changed this in my own project, it went from refusing to build to doing an auto-build on opening the project. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Go File,Project Structure or press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S,

Go Facets, Select your android project, in the structure there are configuration files, folders. [Image of structure tab (before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uyp7.png)

Location of AndroidManifest file was like this: D:\Programming\Dart Flutter Projects\tip_calculator\AndroidManifest.xml

Change the location like this. [Image of strcuture tab (after)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HikR.png)

Changed it to here: D:\Programming\Dart Flutter Projects\tip_calculator\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Goto File -> New Project -> Android Project->continue and hit Finish.

Now go to File -> Import existing file system

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem this way: I created another project using the default configuration and without closing this new project opened the old project with the Android Source Generator: [project] AndroidManifest.xml file not found ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

When I checkout an android project use Android Studio, I see the same problem. I try to new an Android module in the project, then the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Move your project folder to default project directory

**/home/USER/AndroidStudioProjects/**

This solves my issue .
Hope This helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Open the Gradle Sync tab, check for any errors there.  If there is a link to "Install Repository and sync project" click it to install the missing components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flutter build apk`. Just type the following in your terminal:

```
 flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```