# AndroidManifest.xml file not found:Maven+ Android Studio

Tags: android, git, maven

I am using Android Studio and am new to it.I have used git to clone the project from the repository. Also I am using Maven and building the project.

When I try to make the project, am getting error like AndroidManifest.xml not found.Please help me out.

I know this is a duplicate question as I have gone through the links:
[AndroidManifest.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908222/androidmanifest-xml-file-not-found)
[ERROR: Android Source Generator: [project] AndroidManifest.xml file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911346/error-android-source-generator-project-androidmanifest-xml-file-not-found)
But both links are not able to solve my problem.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue on Android Studio, what you are missing is adding your **sources** under **module** source settings.

Add your content root and mark `build` & `src/main` as **sources**

It should look like this

[image]

Comment: i m pretty sure this is the fix.. it works for me, check again carefully, what all folders are marked as source..

Comment: I am working on maven multiple projects and also I am modifying them. In the source file, I have src\main and generated but there is no build file.

Comment: for maven i guess it is target folder instead of build.. also if there are some apk libs module add their dependencies as well.. i will recommend to use IntelliJ Idea CE edition instead of Android studio. As studio is tightly coupled with gradle. It has all features and same look n feel of android studio. Infact studio is based on IntelliJ Idea

Comment: target folder in excluded folder. Also I want to know,the problem which i mentioned ,is it due to Android Studio?