# import project from git is missing manifest file

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I have a project in bitbucket that I imported from git. But I get the following error that says my manifest file is not found:

[image]

But this is very puzzling since the manifest file is right there under the `res` directory.

Can someone please explain what is wrong here?

UPDATE:

When I imported the projected it said it failed to load the app.iml module and c4k.iml module. Does this have any importance?

Comment: I always try **not** to use the IDE. Simple `git clone` the repo and then `import project -> select the build.gradle`.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525969/androidmanifest-xml-is-missing

Comment: How/where do I simple `git clone` the repo?

Comment: Manifest should not go in res/ directory but in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try not to use the IDE. So try using the command line.

1. Simply `git clone <repo>` the repo
2. Then, in Intellij/Android Studio, `File -> Import Project` -> `Select the build.gradle`

Comment: Really? A down vote? At least explain why or give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Alt + F12 to open the console in android studio.
   OR open the console app (cmd on Windows, terminal on OS X, shell on Linux)
2. `git clone <here paste the repo URL from  the GitHub page >`
3. Import by instruction in the other answer.