# How do I increase the speed of searches in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse searches on internal files suddenly became very slow, is there any way to increase the speed on searches in Eclipse?

Are there any configuration changes or Eclipse settings that would speed up searches?

Comment: Buy a faster computer :D

Comment: I have asked about the changes in the .ini files of eclipse..My configuration is w7 proffessional with 8 gb ram and eclipse indigo..

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what language you are working in or the eclipse version.  For eclipse luna on an Angularjs project, I was able to filter out searches using derived resources as I didn't need to look through node_modules or bower_components.

There is a potential for creating problems however, but not in my case here.  It took my searches down to just a few seconds on a large project.  Just right click on a folder, go to properties, and mark a folder as derived. Derived entities are excluded from searching by default, so for an angularjs application, skipping bower_components and node_modules made it very fast!

There are other solutions, such as creating a Working Set with the folders you want to include in your searches, depending on the size and type of your project.

Here is a similar question on SO: [Exclude folders from Eclipse search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/exclude-folders-from-eclipse-search) with more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so, there is any `eclipse.ini` configuration for this purpose.

The searches are the specific to the internal algorithms used in particular eclipse distribution.

I would suggest to upgrade your Eclipse distribution to latest [Eclipse Juno 4.2 SR2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Thank you ajduke...but i have heard there are some parameters in .ini file to increase the cache memory of eclipse that ultimately increases the speed of internal search..

Comment: Are you sure? because i am referring to official doc for same [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). I didnt see any mention of the search option