# eclipse hide a item entirely from processing

Tags: eclipse, project-explorer

My requirement: To hide specific file/folder from the project explorer.

Following the steps given on below link, i am able to successfully do so,
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm

But, I want to hide them entirely from the processing, e.g. If I do a search for some word in *.java files, results show up from the hidden folder as well. Any way to exclude it from search results (or from entire processing of what eclipse looks for) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude folders from Eclipse search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443169/exclude-folders-from-eclipse-search)

Comment: Got the answer. check.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111002/1135954

Answer (score 0):

Resources marked as 'derived' are ignored by most things.

You can set the derived flag on the 'Resource' tab of the file or folder Properties.

You can use the `IResource.setDerived` method to set the flag programatically.