# How to exclude .svn directories from search in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Eclipse file search not include svn directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934/how-can-i-make-eclipse-file-search-not-include-svn-directories)

I would like to perform a search but exclude all .svn directories from the search. How could I do that?

By the way, I have the Subversive plugin installed in Eclipse, if it's needed.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

1. Open project's Properties.
2. Resource/Resource Filters
3. Click Add... button.
4. Configure filter:

   - Filter type: Exclude all
   - Applies to: Folders
   - x All children (recursive)
   - Leave selected positions in combobox (Name, matches) and type `.svn`
   - Click OK

It works OK for me.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Just remember (unlike me) to repeat this for each project you have open.

Comment: Another pattern that works is \*.svn\*

Comment: rocking. ty. in osx i thought there was some way to make this a system-wide default, but i'm not finding it.

Comment: I had to refreseh (right click on project -> refresh) my project manually in order for this to work. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason it only worked for me if I selected "Files and Folders" from step 4.

Comment: good to know and of course it works with any .git .svn .old .private directories..

Answer (score 3):

I think that the easiest way is creating a *Working Set*:

1. Open Search dialog (`Ctrl+h`)
2. Change search scope to `Working Set`
3. Click `Choose` ...
4. Click `New` to create a new *Working Set* with the what you want searched (alternatively you can `Add All` and then remove the ones you want filtered (the .svn dirs).

Hope it helps

Comment: This does not work great as there are .svn folders in folder/package in the tree.